# Possible to resolve actual domain from d-00000000000.ampproject.net?

Tags: c#, web, dns, network-traffic, accelerated-mobile-page

Regarding --- https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/

I have a C# app (not that it probably matters), attempts DNS and Reverse DNS lookups for traffic logging/analysis purposes.  I've noticed that a lot of the mobile traffic points to a google owned set of IPs and then resolves back to something like:

ord37s08-in-f14.1e100.net

And then diving deeper, I see other host names, like this:

d-[long numeric string].ampproject.net

d-[different long numeric string].ampproject.net

d-[different long numeric string].ampproject.net

Considering what AMP is/does (and I realize the result won't be 100% perfect or could up having multiple results for a single request), is there a way to determine the actual hostname that is/was behind these type AMP host names?

Thanks!